# WordPress pagination not working on home page ( Custom templete )

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I have googled the problem, I am worried not only me there are many coder who faces this problem. I applied there fixing but same result. Would you please review my pagination code? I have a static front page, where pagination redirects me to homepage (`/`). If I add after url `/page/2` manually this one also redirect me to homepage. I know this is childish question but I can't figure out the problem.

This is the function.

```
 function pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
 {  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<ul class='pagenavi'>";
         if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo;</a></li>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo;</a></li>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='current' >".$i."</a></li>":"<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a></li>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>&rsaquo;</a></li>";  
         if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li><a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>&raquo;</a></li>";
         echo "</ul>\n";
     }
}
```

Code used to generate pagination

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'paged' => $paged, 'cat'=> $bcatid, 'posts_per_page' => 9 ) );
?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
post content
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php pagination(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to get the current pagination number on a static front page (Page template) you have to use the 'page' query variable:

`$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;`

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: I added your code instead of `if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;` Still I am redirecting to homepage. Any solution? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried updating the permalinks again? Also what plugins do you have installed, is there any that can interfere with the site's functionality? Also, do you have set the static front page as a custom `home.php` file in your template file or via Wordpress Settings -> Reading Settings -> Front page displays -> A static page (select below)  ?

Comment: I have lot of plugins for SEO, Breakcrumbs etc. Yes I have custom template name `template_home_blog3.php` I set is as static home page. And permalink like %postname%.html. I have updated permalink, changed to another etc. But didn't work. I have wp super cache plugin installed too. I cleared cache. I did almost everything, cannot make it working. Thanks Eek for your comment.

Comment: Try changing the name of `template_home_blog3.php` to `home.php` that might actually do the trick :)

Comment: I have another page named home.php. Thanks.

Comment: Well, you're problem is more complex. If you wanna fix it I would copy the content from `template_home_blog3.php` to `home.php` (home.php isn't used at anything for your website right now) and change the display of the front page back to posts. Try it. If it doesn't work I suggest going on a fresh install with no plugins and then starting to add plugins, If it works, then that's that. :)