# WordPress posts_link navigates to next page but posts stay the same

Tags: wordpress, pagination

I'm using next_posts_link() and previous_posts_link() to display navigation on my post listing page. The previous link appears but when I click it, it takes me to a new page (/page/2/) but the posts do not change, still shows the same two posts.

This is a page that's currently set to the front page/home page. I'm guessing this is the problem? Because this same code is working on other sites I've used it on...

```
<?php 
// the query
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array (
'posts_per_page'         => '2',
'post_type'              => 'post',
'paged'                  => $paged
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>
```

And my closing:

```
<?php   
wp_reset_postdata();
endwhile; 
endif;
?>

<div class="post-nav">
   <?php next_posts_link( '&laquo; earlier posts', 0 ); ?>
   <?php previous_posts_link( 'recent posts &raquo;' ) ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured this out had to change:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

to

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

Found the answer here:

[WordPress pagination not working on home page ( Custom templete )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982212/wordpress-pagination-not-working-on-home-page-custom-templete)